# FCIV recursive verification on a xml file

Tags: hash, checksum

Copying files folder to files_copy folder, one wants to check the files were copied correctly. Fciv.exe permits to make an xml database of the original files and then compare it to the copied destination:

Taking an xml database recursively for the original folder:

```
fciv.exe -add C:\files -wp -xml C:\hashDB.xml -r
```

works fine, all files listed.

But when one tries to verify the contents of the copied directory against the xml DB of the original location, there is apparently no way to insert the -r switch so the destination gets checked recursively. I've tried with all the combinations, base sample here:

C:\files_copy>fciv -v -xml C:\hashDB.xml -r

If used without the -r switch, the output will always be successful and report no files modified (not true).
How to recursively check the destination with fciv? Is is possible?

Answer (score -1):

not sure if you still need this answer or not, but I ran into the same problem recently. The -wp flag stores only the filenames in the XML file, not the entire path. When fciv -r is called to read and verify the hashes in the XML file, it assumes that the files are included in the current directory if there isn't a full path next to the filename. Try running fciv without the -wp flag, then when running the verification, you shouldn't need the -r flag to search within folders.

Comment: I just tried that but got an "All files verified successfully", even thou a file was modified in the destination folder. So I'm not really sure this thing works. In the output I also got a "Could not create a registry key", but that shouldn't interfere with the checksum operations.